# Why is the result of the AVG function null?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I don't know what to do. Why all avgTime = null?

This is my entity class:

```
public class ResidentDto {
private Integer residentId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private Long avgTime;
public ResidentDto() {}
public ResidentDto(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.email = email;     }
```

getters and setters

This is property:

```
resident.avg.diff.time=SELECT RESIDENT_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL,  AVG(DATEDIFF('DAY',  ARRIVAL_TIME, DEPARTURE_TIME)) FROM RESIDENT GROUP BY RESIDENT_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL
```

My method:

```
public class ResidentDtoDaoJdbc implements ResidentDaoDto {
@Value("${resident.avg.diff.time}")
private String findAllAvgDateSQL;

private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
private RowMapper rowMapper = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(ResidentDto.class);

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResidentDaoJdbc.class);

public ResidentDtoDaoJdbc(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
}
public List<ResidentDto> findAvgDate() {
LOGGER.debug("find all avg(Date): ");
return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(findAllAvgDateSQL, rowMapper);}
```

And my test method:

```
@Test
public void findAvgDateTest() {
List<ResidentDto> residentList = residentDaoDto.findAvgDate();
Assertions.assertNotNull(residentList);
Assertions.assertTrue(residentList.size() > 0);
}
```

I have list's value like this:

```
ResidentDto{residentId=1, firstName='Stephen', lastName='King', email='stephenking@test.com', avgTime=null}
ResidentDto{residentId=2, firstName='Margaret', lastName='Mitchell', email='margaretmitchell@test.com', avgTime=null}
ResidentDto{residentId=3, firstName='Den', lastName='Brown', email='denbrown@test.com', avgTime=null}
ResidentDto{residentId=4, firstName='Erih', lastName='Remark', email='remark@test.com', avgTime=null}
```

Also, I use H2 in Intellij from memory.

Comment: Have you tried using an alias for the avg function : `AVG(DATEDIFF('DAY',  ARRIVAL_TIME, DEPARTURE_TIME)) AVG_TIME`

Comment: Given the column as either no alias, or maybe a standard alias like `AVG`,  it is not going to get mapped to a field called `avgTime`. You need to explicitly alias to `AVG_TIME`.

Comment: Thank you  Gautham M and  Mark Rottevee. You are right. When I added an alias behind an expression I had a correct result. Thank you very much.